# NestJS + TypeORM - Error connecting to both mysql and mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, nestjs, typeorm

I am just learning about NestJS and I have been trying to get an application to connect to both mysql and mongodb for some time and I just can't get it to work.  The error I am getting is as follows:

> > Nest can't resolve dependencies of the AppService (UserMRepository, ?). Please make sure that the argument at index [1] is available in the AppModule context.

This is a simple NestJS generated app that simply connects to two databases and will create a record in each database when getHello() is called.

app.module.ts

```
import { AppController } from './app.controller';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { User } from './entity/User.entity';
import { UserM } from './entity/User.mongo';


@Module({
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
      "name": "default",
      "type": "mongodb",
      "host": "localhost",
      "port": 27017,
      "database": "typeorm",
      "useNewUrlParser": true,
      "useUnifiedTopology": true,
      "entities": [
        "src/**/**.mongo.ts",
        "dist/**/**.mongo.js"
      ],
    }),   
    TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
      "name": "mysql",
      "type": "mysql",
      "host": "localhost",
      "port": 3306,
      "username": "typeorm",
      "password": "typeorm",
      "database": "typeorm",
      "entities": [
        "src/**/**.entity.ts",
        "dist/**/**.entity.js"
      ],
    }),
    TypeOrmModule.forFeature([UserM]),
    TypeOrmModule.forFeature([User], 'mysql'),
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

app.service.ts

```
import { InjectRepository } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { Repository, MongoRepository, getRepository, DeleteResult } from 'typeorm';
import { User} from "./entity/User.entity";
import { UserM } from './entity/User.mongo';

@Injectable()
export class AppService {
  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(UserM)
    @InjectRepository(User)
    private readonly userMRepository: Repository<UserM>,
    private readonly userRepository: Repository<User>,
  ) {}

  async getHello(): Promise<string> {
    var userM = new UserM();
    userM.firstName = "Timber";
    userM.lastName = "Saw";
    userM.age = 25;
    var newUser1 = await this.userMRepository.save(userM);

    var user = new User();
    user.firstName = "Timber";
    user.lastName = "Saw";
    user.age = 25;
    var newUser2 = await this.userRepository.save(user);

    return;
  }
}
```

I can confirm that will successfully work with each database individually but when I try both together it keeps failing.  I have read all the posts on this and tried various ways of setting this up so not sure what I am doing wrong.  Is someone able to see what I am doing wrong?

Paul

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The constructor should be fixed:

```
constructor(
    @InjectRepository(UserM)
    private readonly userMRepository: Repository<UserM>,
    @InjectRepository(User, 'mysql')
    private readonly userRepository: Repository<User>,
  ) {}
```

Comment: Thanks Tano, I tried that but it didn't work.  I am getting the same error.

Comment: First of all, you should remove one of the entities path, since it doesnt make sense to use them twice. I assume that the user.entity is annotated with @Entity and the  the typeorm database exists in mysql. Please add  "synchronize": true to mysql connection to see if it can connect to it. the typeorm cant create the database in mysql only in mongo. If you can see more errors, share with me

Comment: Tano, the Entities are slightly different in that the "UserM" uses ObjectID type for mongodb whereas "User" has an int type.  I have been able to confirm that the connection to each database works successfully as I have commented the respective code for each database in turn and the uncommented database works successfully.  It seems like the issue is more that NestJS itself is having an issue with both connections in parallel.

Comment: you can add the connection to the injectrepository annotation. Try it please!